# Truncate Plugin Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, truncate

I'm currently creating an jQuery Plugin called Truncate - The Purpose of it is to shorten a passage.

The problem is that the first time you click **Show More** instead of sliding down the hidden part of the paragraph, it just shows it.

My Defaults are:

```
 var defaults = {
            length: 120,
            MinExtra: 50,
            ShowMoreText: 'Show More',
            ShowLessText: 'Show Less',
            EllipsisText: '...',
            ShowLessAndMoreColor: 'black',
            SlideDownTime: 700,
            SlideUpTime: 700
        };
```

Then I have the little var to make it function:

```
var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

With some extra code:

```
 this.each(function() {
            obj = $(this);
            var body = obj.html();
            obj1 = $(this);
            var body1 = obj1.html();
```

Then I have the main code which is:

```
if (body1.length > options.length + options.MinExtra) {
                var splitLocation = body1.indexOf(' ', options.length);
                if (splitLocation != -1) {
                    // truncate tip
                    splitLocation = body1.indexOf(' ', options.length);
                    var str1 = body1.substring(0, splitLocation);
                    var str2 = body1.substring(splitLocation, body1.length - 1);
                    obj.html(str1 + '<span class="truncate_ellipsis">' + options.EllipsisText + '</span>' + '<span class="truncate_more">' + str2 + '</span>');
                    obj.find('.truncate_more').css("display", "none");
                    // insert more link
                    obj.append('<div class="clearboth" style="cursor:pointer;color:' + options.ShowLessAndMoreColor + ';">' + '<a href="#" class="truncate_more_link">' + options.ShowMoreText + '</a>' + '</div>');
                    // set onclick event for more/less link
                    var moreLinki = $('.truncate_more_link', obj1);
                    var moreContenti = $('.truncate_more', obj1);
                    var ellipsisi = $('.truncate_ellipsis', obj1);
                    moreLinki.click(function() {
                        if (moreLinki.text() == options.ShowMoreText) {
                            moreContenti.slideDown(options.SlideDownTimer);
                            moreLinki.text(options.ShowLessText);
                            ellipsisi.css("display", "none");
                        }
                        else {
                            moreContenti.slideUp(options.SlideUpTime);
                            moreLinki.text(options.ShowMoreText);
                            ellipsisi.css("display", "inline");
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You can start it using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').Truncate();
});
```

Or define options with it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').Truncate({
    length: 120,
            MinExtra: 50,
            ShowMoreText: 'Show More',
            ShowLessText: 'Show Less',
            EllipsisText: '...',
            ShowLessAndMoreColor: 'black',
            SlideDownTime: 700,
            SlideUpTime: 700


});
});
```

Still don't understand the problem? Please see the [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAhsp/).

Hope someone can give me any *idea* of how to stop this. Thanks!

Comment: Click on the button three times in a row. Strange...

Comment: @Blender I see this too. It is indeed very strange. And when you slide it back up, the last line to slide up does it a little slower and not with the rest. *Very* strange...

Comment: So much overkill for truncate. Check out my snippet: http://alienwebguy.blogspot.com/2011/09/truncating-article-text-in-seo-friendly.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the span initially has a display set to `inline`. and inline elements don't use width and height, so you cant animate them. Once you finish a `slideDown` it becomes `inline-block` so subsequent `slideUp` and `slideDown` animations work.

You can "fix" it by setting it to be `inline-block` before hiding it.

```
obj.find('.truncate_more').css("display", "inline-block").hide();
```

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/LAhsp/2/

The only issue is that it appears on a new line. But this happens in your version as well ( after initially opening and closing it).

Comment: WOW Thanks! I owe you one! Ever need help, feel free to email: shawn@weebuild.biz

Comment: np, if you can accept the answer and/or upvote that would be thanks enough.